# Linux Driver - Sharing a WaitHandle (-like) with user space

Tags: linux, events, signals, driver, wait

I have a Windows device driver that I'd like to port to Linux.

Our user-space application often needs to wait for driver events. Here's the mechanism that we use on Windows :

1. The application creates a WaitHandle
2. The application gives this WaitHandle to the driver through an ioctl
3. The driver can access this handle using ObReferenceObjectByHandle and set it with KeSetEvent

What I like with this:

- The WaitHandle can come from anywhere (can be AutoReset or ManualReset, can be a .Net WaitHandle etc.)
- The process doesn't have to make an ioctl to sleep, but just can call the usual WaitForSingleObject.

I'd like to keep the same architecture in my Linux driver.

Does anyone know how I could get the same behaviour on Linux ?

Comment: Did you consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink ? And I believe you should redesign your driver for Linux, not just port a Windows driver to Linux!

Comment: That seems a bit over complicated ! I just want a wait queue. Actually 98% of my driver is os-independant C code, there are just a few basic system calls that I need to adapt from one OS to another...

Comment: Then most of your code (e.g. your wait queue) is inside a user-space daemon. Keep the kernel part minimal!

Comment: You should tell more about your driver. What kind of hardware does it support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple idea would be to create a character device with blocking read. User application reads from the device; such read blocks until the event happens.

**Edit:**

Another idea is to [send signal to userspace application](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#s6) whose handler will set the userspace wait handle (futex probably).

Comment: A char device is just not a synchronization primitive, that looks like a strange idea :/. In addition to that, I may have up to ~30 of those events (associated to communication pipes), I'm not going to create a char device for each of them...

Comment: @Julien: Another idea is to send signal to userspace application (http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#s6) whose handler will set the userspace wait handle (futex probably).

Comment: Events could be sent (e.g. on Netlink) with a different data packet for each. Then you only need one char device, or one netlink. And you need to define a protocol.

Comment: @Servateur Yeah that looks like a very nice idea ! Thanks man ! Please edit your answer and I'll accept it.